# If value in Column A matches value in Column B then return ALL matches in Column C

Tags: excel-formula

So I have three columns I'm working with.

The first is a list of category IDs. 
The second and third are category ID matched with unique user IDs.

I'm trying to say if the value in Column A matches the value in Column B, then return the value of every instance in Column C. `VLOOKUP` only returns the first value where there's a match, and I'm trying to return all values where there's a match.Thanks for any help!

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the built features of excel and look for filter.  trying to read your question, its sounds like you are just trying to display the unique user IDs based on a selected category ID.  Your question states you want this information to show up in column C but this is where all your data is.  So you are either intending to do it once and wipping out non matching data, or you want to display your results in a different column if you are going to go about this with a formula.

Answer (score 0):

Try this array formula in `Cell D5` and drag to the right and down:

```
={INDEX($C:$C, SMALL(IF($A$1=$B:$B, ROW($B:$B)-MIN(ROW($B:$B))+1, ""), COLUMN(A1)))}
```

It will give all matches for the value in `Cell A1` in a horizontal list.

---

<sub>Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. If entered correctly, Excel with wrap the formula in braces (e.g. **{** and **}**). You do not type the braces in yourself. Once entered into the first cell correctly, they can be filled or copied down or right just like any other formula. Try and reduce your full-column references to ranges more closely representing the extents of your actual data. Array formulas chew up calculation cycles logarithmically so it is good practise to narrow the referenced ranges to a minimum. See [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) for more information.</sub>